# Hibernate, использование CSV FK для загрузки объектов

Tags: hibernate, java, sql

**А**, **Б** - таблицы

**А** содержит столбец с csv строкой, состоящих из id элементов из таблицы **Б**

Можно ли загрузить Объект **А** + список объектов **Б**?

```
@Entity
Class A {
...
   List<B> list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы сначала разберитесь в терминах SQL как это все безобразие выглядит, а потом уже пробуйте это выразить в терминах Hibernate. Hibernate всего лишь некий [ORM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) применительно к Java, ну типа SQL<->Java, так что первоисточник проблемы именно в SQL.

*P.S. Что это за мода пошла такая пытаться разбираться в следствиях, а не в причинах?*

*P.P.S. Включаю тег SQL: в ожидании криков раненых в самое сердце sql'истов :)*